# distribution convergence N(0,σ^2/n)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Consider the [sequence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sequence.htmhttps://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sequence.html) $X_1, X_2 \dots$ where each $X_n$ has a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) $\mathcal{N}(0, σ ^ 2 / n)$. Let us show that $X_n$ [converges](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convergent.html) in [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) to 0.

$$F_{X_n} (x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2/n}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{\frac{-u^2}{2(\sigma^2/n)}}du$$

My question is: Why is the [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)) of the distribution function as follows? how do you get there from the equation above?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n} (x) =  \begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{si}\ x < 0, \\
      \frac{1}{2} & \text{si}\ x = 0, \\
      1 & \text{si}\ x > 0.
   \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: with $v = u\sqrt{n}/\sigma$,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2/n}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-u^2 / (2 \sigma^2/n)} \, du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x\sqrt{n}/\sigma} e^{-v^2/2} \, dv.$$
Then take $n \to \infty$.

---

Instead of working with integrals, it may be easier to note that $X_n = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} Z$ where $Z \sim N(0,1)$. So $P(X_n \le x) = P(Z \le \frac{x\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x\sqrt{n}/\sigma} e^{-v^2/2} \, dv$.

Comment: @JuanBromas If you take the limit of what I've written above as $n \to \infty$, you'll get the second image.

Comment: @JuanBromas: I think that this is the answer to your question. Literally, you just have to take the limit (of the integral in the first hint) for the three different cases of $x$.

Comment: @JuanBromas The integral I've written is equal to $P(Z \le x \sqrt{n}/\sigma)$ where $Z \sim N(0,1)$. When $x$ is positive, then $x \sqrt{n} / \sigma \to \infty$ so the probability becomes $P(Z < \infty) = 1$.